# Atop shows MDD stuck at 100%

Tags: raid, lvm, diskmanagement, atop

After investigating a load spike on my CentOS 7 server, I ran atop and noticed something odd.
It is reporting MDD for my logical volume (md127) maxed out at 100% all the time.

[image]

The other disk tests I ran seemed fine. It is a RAID1 config with two 500G SD drives.
Any suggestions why this might be? It looks like it has been this way for a while.

```
[root@ds2 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md126 : active raid1 sdb3[2] sda3[0]
      1049536 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[2]
      478291968 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 3/4 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is doing the same with RAID 1 config.
It however does not seem to generate any load on the system.
I ran 'sar' and %iowait is also below 0.5% at all times.

I can assume this is normal behaviour for RAID 1?